# Find and Change specific item from an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm dealing with an array like

`arr = [{id:'first',name:'John'},{id:'fifth',name:'Kat'},{id:'eitghth',name:'Isa'}]`. Now i want to give condition to the array like if i get id 'fifth' in array, The array will change to

`arr = [{id:'first',name:'John'},{id:'sixth',name:'Kat'},{id:'eitghth',name:'Isa'}]`

Like just one part of an item is modified. How can i do that in js?

Comment: That doesn't seems to make any sense in my opinion (XY problem). Anyway, just lookup for the element and replace its id. You can do that in several ways, like using `find`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to locate the entry, and then simply update its `id` attribute:

```js
const arr = [{id:'first',name:'John'},{id:'fifth',name:'Kat'},{id:'eitghth',name:'Isa'}];

const entry = arr.find(item => item.id === 'fifth');
entry.id = 'sixth';

console.log(arr);
```

You can also use [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to retrieve the index of the entry that you want to replace, and modify it accordingly:

```js
const arr = [{id:'first',name:'John'},{id:'fifth',name:'Kat'},{id:'eitghth',name:'Isa'}];

const targetIndex = arr.findIndex(item => item.id === 'fifth');
arr[targetIndex].id = 'sixth';

console.log(arr);
```

---

However, the two methods above only help to find the **first matching element**. If you have multiple entries in the array with the ID of `fifth`, then you are better off using iteration:

```js
const arr = [{id:'fifth',name:'Kat'},{id:'fifth',name:'Kat'},{id:'fifth',name:'Kat'}];

arr.forEach(item => {
  if (item.id === 'fifth') {
    item.id = 'sixth';
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```